# JS: Search Bar Ignore Accented Characters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, tooltip

I'm making a Search Bar Tool project on Javascript and I need help with someting.

I need to filter words correctly when they have accented letters on my search bar tool.

This is the part of the code that handles this filter:

```
const newFilter = data.filter((value) => {
      return value.Descricao.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord.toLowerCase())
    });
```

Example: São Paulo appearing when I type "sao".

This code can handle only lowercase typing, any idea on how to add this function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove accents/diacritics in a string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/990904/remove-accents-diacritics-in-a-string-in-javascript)